# How to create new admin page

Tags: admin, adminhtml

I'm using Magento 1.9.0.1 and i've created a new extension in which i've added a new tab in the admin panel take a look at the picture.

[image]

Here is what i have in my files.

In: /app/code/community/VivasIndustries/SmsNotification/etc/config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <VivasIndustries_SmsNotification>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </VivasIndustries_SmsNotification>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <models>
        <smsnotification>
            <class>VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Model</class>
        </smsnotification>
    </models>  
    <events>
        <sales_order_save_after>
            <observers>
                <vivasindustries_smsnotification>
                    <class>smsnotification/observer</class>
                    <method>orderSaved</method>
                </vivasindustries_smsnotification>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_save_after>
    </events>
    <helpers>
        <smsnotification>
            <class>VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Helper</class>
        </smsnotification>
        <adminhtml>
            <rewrite>
                <data>VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Helper_Adminhtml_Data</data>
            </rewrite>
        </adminhtml>
    </helpers>
  </global>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <VivasIndustries_SmsNotification before="Mage_Adminhtml">VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Adminhtml</VivasIndustries_SmsNotification>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```

Here is what i have in: /app/code/community/VivasIndustries/SmsNotification/etc/adminhtml.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <menu>
        <vivassms translate="title" module="smsnotification">
            <title>SMS Center</title>
            <sort_order>110</sort_order>
            <children>
                <sendsms translate="title" module="smsnotification">
                    <title>Send SMS</title>
                    <action>adminhtml/magesms_sendsms</action>
                    <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                </sendsms>
                <settings>
                    <title>Settings</title>
                    <action>adminhtml/system_config/edit/section/vivas/</action>
                    <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                </settings>
                <about translate="title" module="smsnotification">
                    <title>About</title>
                    <action>adminhtml/smsnotification_about</action>
                    <sort_order>11</sort_order>
                </about>
            </children>
        </vivassms>
    </menu>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <vivassms>
                        <title>SMS</title>
                        <children>
                            <sendsms translate="title" module="smsnotification">
                                <title>Send SMS</title>
                            </sendsms>
                            <settings>
                                <title>Settings</title>
                                <children>
                                    <smsprofile translate="title" module="smsnotification">
                                        <title>Edit user account</title>
                                    </smsprofile>
                                </children>
                            </settings>
                            <about translate="title" module="smsnotification">
                                <title>About</title>
                            </about>
                        </children>
                    </vivassms>
                    <system>
                        <children>
                            <config>
                                <children>
                                    <vivassms translate="title" module="smsnotification">
                                        <title>Vivas SMS</title>
                                    </vivassms>
                                </children>
                            </config>
                        </children>
                    </system>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

I've added these three children tabs to the created new tab `SMS Center` but when i click on the `About` tab i got error 404 ON MY FRONTEND. This is awkward. Why i got redirected to the frontend ?

Can you please help me out to create a simple new custom page in the admin panel where i want to add a simple text?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things you will need to get going: a controller, and proper paths to the controller in your adminhtml.xml.

Here is what you'll need in your controller for the first link:

```
class VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Adminhtml_MagesmsController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{

    /**
     * Grid action for ajax requests
     */
    public function sendsmsAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->_setActiveMenu('vivassms');
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

This will get you a blank page within the Magento admin.

You should also updated your adminhtml from this:

```
<sendsms translate="title" module="smsnotification">
    <title>Send SMS</title>
    <action>adminhtml/magesms_sendsms</action>
    <sort_order>1</sort_order>
</sendsms>
```

to this:

```
<sendsms translate="title" module="smsnotification">
    <title>Send SMS</title>
    <action>adminhtml/magesms/sendsms</action>
    <sort_order>1</sort_order>
</sendsms>
```

Comment: It worked great for me, i just had to modify the action to something like this:
**<action>vivasindustries_smsnotification_admin/magesms/sendsms</action>**